# terminal (bash) run program on other machine without copying it across

Tags: java, bash

Is there a way (using the terminal - bash) I can run a program using someone else's processor, ram , monitor, speakers, etc but have the program stored on my machine?

To explain:

Now I have a java program which when I want to run on another machine, I SCP the class/jar file across, then ssh in and run it.

Is it possible, while ssh ed in, for me to then load a program from my own hard drive into the other computers RAM and run it?

Secondly:

More specific to java, if I want to parallel process a program, is there a way I can make the program run threads on another machines processor?

Comment: See this question -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400139/multi-node-concurrency-in-java

Comment: I don't think so.  Somehow, that remote computer needs to have the instructions to execute the software.

Answer (score 2):

If the computer that has the program can host a shared folder (samba/nfs/etc), then you can mount that on the other computer, then run it like that.